# Drag and drop issue when adding div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I use jQuery UI drag and drop functionality. I had a table with 2 columns. The items were in one column and user could drag them into another table column. Everything worked great. However, I needed to wrap the elements in the first column with a div in order to add a vertical scroll when there were too many items. Now when I try to drag the elements it seems I'm dragging them within the same div, into the hidden area, instead of into the next table column. I've tried to restrict the div width but get the same results. What am I missing?

Here's my **HTML**:

```
<table id="tbl">
<tr valign="top">
    <td id="dragFrom" class="ui-droppable"><div id="myOverflow"></div></td>
    <td id="dropTo"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
#dragFrom {
    width: 290px
}

#myOverflow{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 290px
}
```

Comment: Some JSFiddle example code would help us a lot, santa :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I just figured out the solution that works. Hopefully someone finds it useful:

```
#myOverflow{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto
}
```